# Message not showing on PHP form when email received

Tags: php, forms

I tested to receive to my own email, for some reason I get everything but its not showing the content of what I type. It doesnt show the actual message when I receive it. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
      <div class="contact-heading">
      </div>
      <form role="form" class="contact-form" action="contact-us.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="exampleInputPassword1">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name:" required >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="E-Mail:" required >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail3">Company</label>
          <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Company:" required >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail4">Message</label>
          <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="message" rows="8" id="exampleInputEmail4" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>

      </form>
    </div>


    <?php 
           $to = 'emailsample@yahoo.com'; 
           $subject  = "Contact us";

$name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']); 
$email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']); 
$company = stripslashes($_REQUEST['company']); 
$message = stripslashes($_REQUEST['message']); 
$msg .= "Name: ".$name."\r\n";  
$msg .= "E-mail: ".$email."\r\n";  
$msg .= "Company: ".$company."\r\n"; 
$message .= "Topicjk: ".$message."\r\n";  
$msg .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n\n"; 
$msg .= "---Message--- \r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n\n"; 

$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:".$email); 

if($mail) {
header("Location:contact-us.html"); 
} else {
echo 'Message could not be sent! Please try again.';   
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not passing `$message` (which has content) to mail in this line.

Change from

`$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:".$email);`

To

`$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:".$email);`

or

Change from

`$message .= "Topicjk: ".$message."\r\n";`

To

`$msg .= "Topicjk: ".$message."\r\n";`

Comment: Thank you so much!